# python code to find feature importances after kmeans clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, feature-selection

I researched the ways to find the feature importances (my dataset just has 9 features).Following are the two methods to do so, But i am having difficulty to write the python code.

I am looking to rank each of the features who's influencing the cluster formation.

1. Calculate the variance of the centroids for every dimension. The dimensions with the highest variance are most important in distinguishing the clusters.
2. If you have only a little number of variables you could do some kind of leaving-one-out test (remove 1 var and redo clustering). Also keep in mind that k-means depends on the initialization, so you want to keep that fixed when you redo the clustering.

Any python codes to accomplish this?

Comment: Somewhat related discussion in [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491197/scikit-learn-finding-the-features-that-contribute-to-each-kmeans-cluster)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

Lets say we have X with 200 samples and 9 variables, and synthetically make them have two clusters, and just for the sake of visualization, we fill two of these variables at each time.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
X = np.zeros((200,4))

Feature1_1 = np.random.normal(loc=40, scale=1.0, size=100)
Feature1_2 = np.random.normal(loc=70, scale=3.0, size=100)

Feature2_1 = np.random.normal(loc=20, scale=4.0, size=100)
Feature2_2 = np.random.normal(loc=50, scale=1.0, size=100)

X[:100,0]=Feature1_1
X[100:,0]=Feature1_2
X[:100,1]=Feature2_1
X[100:,1]=Feature2_2

plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1])
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Feature 2',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Feature 1',fontsize=18)
```

[image]

Now, lets populate a new feature with a higher variance.

```
Feature3_1 = np.random.normal(loc=40, scale=300.0, size=100)
Feature3_2 = np.random.normal(loc=43, scale=280.0, size=100)

Feature2_1 = np.random.normal(loc=20, scale=4.0, size=100)
Feature2_2 = np.random.normal(loc=50, scale=1.0, size=100)


X[:100,2]=Feature3_1
X[100:,2]=Feature3_2

X[:100,1]=Feature2_1
X[100:,1]=Feature2_2

plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
plt.scatter(X[:,2],X[:,1])
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Feature 3',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Feature 2',fontsize=18)
```

[image]

and a last one with higher variance too

```
Feature3_1 = np.random.normal(loc=40, scale=300.0, size=100)
Feature3_2 = np.random.normal(loc=43, scale=280.0, size=100)

Feature4_1 = np.random.normal(loc=20, scale=40.0, size=100)
Feature4_2 = np.random.normal(loc=22, scale=40.0, size=100)


X[:100,2]=Feature3_1
X[100:,2]=Feature3_2

X[:100,3]=Feature4_1
X[100:,3]=Feature4_2

plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
plt.scatter(X[:,2],X[:,3])
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Feature 3',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Feature 4',fontsize=18)
```

[image]

now, lets cluterize them with k-means

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
```

now, lets visualize those clusters.

```
f1=0
f2=1

plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
plt.scatter(X[kmeans.labels_==0][:,f1],X[kmeans.labels_==0][:,f2])
plt.scatter(X[kmeans.labels_==1][:,f1],X[kmeans.labels_==1][:,f2])
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Feature 3',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Feature 2',fontsize=18)
```

[image]

```
f1=2
f2=1

plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
plt.scatter(X[kmeans.labels_==0][:,f1],X[kmeans.labels_==0][:,f2])
plt.scatter(X[kmeans.labels_==1][:,f1],X[kmeans.labels_==1][:,f2])
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Feature 3',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Feature 2',fontsize=18)
```

[image]

```
f1=2
f2=3

plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
plt.scatter(X[kmeans.labels_==0][:,f1],X[kmeans.labels_==0][:,f2])
plt.scatter(X[kmeans.labels_==1][:,f1],X[kmeans.labels_==1][:,f2])
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Feature 3',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Feature 2',fontsize=18)
```

[image]

we can now very clearly see that feature 3 and 4 are the only important ones. **Note that normalized features would lead to a completely different result.**

And finally, we automate this with:

```
for feature in range(X.shape[1]):
    mean1 = X[kmeans.labels_==0][:,feature].mean()
    mean2 = X[kmeans.labels_==1][:,feature].mean()
    
    var1 = X[kmeans.labels_==0][:,feature].var()
    var2 = X[kmeans.labels_==1][:,feature].var()
    
    print('feature:',feature,'Mean difference:',round(abs(mean1-mean2),3),'Total Variance:',round((var1+var2),3))
```

resulting in:

```
feature: 0 Mean difference: 1.69 Total Variance: 459.464 
feature: 1 Mean difference: 0.879 Total Variance: 449.829 
feature: 2 Mean difference: 66.213 Total Variance: 154932.184 
feature: 3 Mean difference: 2.076 Total Variance: 2731.953
```

Answer (score -1):

The comment is clearly a copy and paste of the documentation, but it wasn't listened the need of the question. these solution are coming from the supervised learning section of the scikit learn user guide.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Consider doing feature selection like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

# UNIVARIATE SELECTION

data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\Briefcase\\PDFs\\1-ALL PYTHON & R CODE SAMPLES\\Feature Selection - Machine Learning\\train.csv')
X = data.iloc[:,0:20]  #independent columns
y = data.iloc[:,-1]    #target column i.e price range

#apply SelectKBest class to extract top 10 best features
bestfeatures = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=10)
fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,y)
dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)
#concat two dataframes for better visualization 
featureScores = pd.concat([dfcolumns,dfscores],axis=1)
featureScores.columns = ['Specs','Score']  #naming the dataframe columns
print(featureScores.nlargest(10,'Score'))  #print 10 best features


# FEATURE IMPORTANCE
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\your_path\\train.csv')
X = data.iloc[:,0:20]  #independent columns
y = data.iloc[:,-1]    #target column i.e price range
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
print(model.feature_importances_) #use inbuilt class feature_importances of tree based classifiers
#plot graph of feature importances for better visualization
feat_importances = pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X.columns)
feat_importances.nlargest(10).plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# Correlation Matrix with Heatmap
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\your_path\\train.csv')
X = data.iloc[:,0:20]  #independent columns
y = data.iloc[:,-1]    #target column i.e price range
#get correlations of each features in dataset
corrmat = data.corr()
top_corr_features = corrmat.index
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
#plot heat map
g=sns.heatmap(data[top_corr_features].corr(),annot=True,cmap="RdYlGn")
```

[image]

```
Dataset is available here:

https://www.kaggle.com/iabhishekofficial/mobile-price-classification#train.csv
```

Comment: But the question is about k means above is a supervised problem? How do the two link

Comment: This answer only works if you know your dependant variables, which indicates a supervised problem, not the case for k-means clustering which is unsupervised

Comment: Oh no. You are right. Sorry about that!